# GPUImage - Focusing and Exposure on tap does not work properly - Missing something?

Tags: ios, focus, gpuimage, avcapturedevice, gpuimagestillcamera

I had starter project that used `AVFoundation` to set up the Camera and it worked perfectly. Now I needed to convert the Camera mechanism into `GPUImage`. I'm using the same focus and exposure method in both projects (which worked prefect at the `AVFoundation` project) but at the `GPUImage` project it doesn't focus properly and the always wrong.

**Don't mind the applies filter it's the same over all of them**

Sample :
**At the top right of the screen you can see the lamb. This is how it get focused + exposure.**

[image]

Set up GPU :

```
stillCamera = GPUImageStillCamera(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480, cameraPosition: .Front)
    CorrectPosition =  AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front
    stillCamera!.outputImageOrientation = .Portrait;
    stillCamera?.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = true
    filter = GPUImageFilter()
    stillCamera?.addTarget(filter)
    filter?.addTarget(self.view as! GPUImageView)
    (self.view as! GPUImageView).fillMode = GPUImageFillModeType.init(2)
```

TouchBegan method:

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        var tap : CGPoint!
        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {
            tap = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        }
        let device: AVCaptureDevice! = self.stillCamera?.inputCamera!
        var error: NSError? = nil
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            if device.focusPointOfInterestSupported && device.isFocusModeSupported(AVCaptureFocusMode.AutoFocus){
                device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.AutoFocus
                device.focusPointOfInterest = tap
            }
            if device.exposurePointOfInterestSupported && device.isExposureModeSupported(AVCaptureExposureMode.AutoExpose){
                device.exposurePointOfInterest = tap
                device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.AutoExpose
            }
            device.subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = monitorSubjectAreaChange
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            print(error)
        } catch {
            fatalError()
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you are probably encountering is the `device.focusPointOfInterest`'s `x` and `y` need to be in `[0;1]` range, where the point `(0,0)` is the left-bottom corner of camera and the `(1,1)` is top-right, while you are passing the coordinates of tap in view's frame coordinate system.

The only thing you need to do is to convert tap's coordinates into your camera points. Note, however, that camera can have different fill modes.

Here is how I am doing conversion (sorry for Objective-C code, but there is mostly simple math):

```
CGPoint tapPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:cameraView];

CGPoint pointOfInterest = [HBFocusUtils convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates:tapPoint inFrame:cameraView.bounds withOrientation:self.currentOrientation andFillMode:cameraView.fillMode mirrored:currentVideoCamera == frontVideoCamera];

[HBFocusUtils setFocus:pointOfInterest forDevice:currentVideoCamera.inputCamera];
```

and the methods' implementation:

```
@implementation HBFocusUtils

+ (CGPoint)convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates:(CGPoint)viewCoordinates inFrame:(CGRect)frame withOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation andFillMode:(GPUImageFillModeType)fillMode mirrored:(BOOL)mirrored;
{
    CGSize frameSize = frame.size;
    CGPoint pointOfInterest = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    if (mirrored)
    {
        viewCoordinates.x = frameSize.width - viewCoordinates.x;
    }

    if (fillMode == kGPUImageFillModeStretch) {
        pointOfInterest = CGPointMake(viewCoordinates.y / frameSize.height, 1.f - (viewCoordinates.x / frameSize.width));
    } else {
        CGSize apertureSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetHeight(frame), CGRectGetWidth(frame));
        if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(apertureSize, CGSizeZero)) {
            CGPoint point = viewCoordinates;
            CGFloat apertureRatio = apertureSize.height / apertureSize.width;
            CGFloat viewRatio = frameSize.width / frameSize.height;
            CGFloat xc = .5f;
            CGFloat yc = .5f;

            if (fillMode == kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio) {
                if (viewRatio > apertureRatio) {
                    CGFloat y2 = frameSize.height;
                    CGFloat x2 = frameSize.height * apertureRatio;
                    CGFloat x1 = frameSize.width;
                    CGFloat blackBar = (x1 - x2) / 2;
                    if (point.x >= blackBar && point.x <= blackBar + x2) {
                        xc = point.y / y2;
                        yc = 1.f - ((point.x - blackBar) / x2);
                    }
                } else {
                    CGFloat y2 = frameSize.width / apertureRatio;
                    CGFloat y1 = frameSize.height;
                    CGFloat x2 = frameSize.width;
                    CGFloat blackBar = (y1 - y2) / 2;
                    if (point.y >= blackBar && point.y <= blackBar + y2) {
                        xc = ((point.y - blackBar) / y2);
                        yc = 1.f - (point.x / x2);
                    }
                }
            } else if (fillMode == kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill) {
                if (viewRatio > apertureRatio) {
                    CGFloat y2 = apertureSize.width * (frameSize.width / apertureSize.height);
                    xc = (point.y + ((y2 - frameSize.height) / 2.f)) / y2;
                    yc = (frameSize.width - point.x) / frameSize.width;
                } else {
                    CGFloat x2 = apertureSize.height * (frameSize.height / apertureSize.width);
                    yc = 1.f - ((point.x + ((x2 - frameSize.width) / 2)) / x2);
                    xc = point.y / frameSize.height;
                }
            }

            pointOfInterest = CGPointMake(xc, yc);
        }
    }

    return pointOfInterest;
}

+ (void)setFocus:(CGPoint)focus forDevice:(AVCaptureDevice *)device
{
    if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] && [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus])
    {
        NSError *error;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
            [device setFocusPointOfInterest:focus];
            [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }

    if ([device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported] && [device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose])
    {
        NSError *error;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
            [device setExposurePointOfInterest:focus];
            [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Hey!  Thank you for your comment! I will test it today! Question :  As far as i understood i need to choose the right "formula" depending on my fillMode right?

Comment: Is this still correct? According to the Apple documentation of focusPointOfInterest: "This property's CGPoint value uses a coordinate system where {0,0} is the top left of the picture area and {1,1} is the bottom right. This coordinate system is always relative to a landscape device orientation with the home button on the right, regardless of the actual device orientation." This seems to contradict the author's comment which says, "where the point (0,0) is the left-bottom corner of camera and the (1,1) is top-right"

Answer (score 3):

**SWift**

1) First Create `HBFocusUtils` Class in Objective-C

2) `#import "HBFocusUtils.h"` in bridge file

```
//Focus on tap
//============
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapOnFocus:"))
tap.delegate = self
filterView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func tapOnFocus(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil)
    {
        let tapPoint = (gestureRecognizer?.locationInView(filterView))! as CGPoint
        let pointOfInterest = HBFocusUtils.convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates(tapPoint, inFrame: filterView.bounds, withOrientation: .Portrait, andFillMode:
            GPUImageFillModeType.init(1), mirrored: true)
        HBFocusUtils.setFocus(pointOfInterest, forDevice: stillCamera.inputCamera)
    }
```

**HBFocusUtils.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "GPUImageView.h"

@interface HBFocusUtils : NSObject

+ (CGPoint)convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates:(CGPoint)viewCoordinates inFrame:(CGRect)frame withOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation andFillMode:(GPUImageFillModeType)fillMode mirrored:(BOOL)mirrored;
+ (void)setFocus:(CGPoint)focus forDevice:(AVCaptureDevice *)device;
@end
```

**HBFocusUtils.m**

```
#import "HBFocusUtils.h"

@implementation HBFocusUtils

+ (CGPoint)convertToPointOfInterestFromViewCoordinates:(CGPoint)viewCoordinates inFrame:(CGRect)frame withOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation andFillMode:(GPUImageFillModeType)fillMode mirrored:(BOOL)mirrored;
{
    CGSize frameSize = frame.size;
    CGPoint pointOfInterest = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    if (mirrored)
    {
        viewCoordinates.x = frameSize.width - viewCoordinates.x;
    }

    if (fillMode == kGPUImageFillModeStretch) {
        pointOfInterest = CGPointMake(viewCoordinates.y / frameSize.height, 1.f - (viewCoordinates.x / frameSize.width));
    } else {
        CGSize apertureSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetHeight(frame), CGRectGetWidth(frame));
        if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(apertureSize, CGSizeZero)) {
            CGPoint point = viewCoordinates;
            CGFloat apertureRatio = apertureSize.height / apertureSize.width;
            CGFloat viewRatio = frameSize.width / frameSize.height;
            CGFloat xc = .5f;
            CGFloat yc = .5f;

            if (fillMode == kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio) {
                if (viewRatio > apertureRatio) {
                    CGFloat y2 = frameSize.height;
                    CGFloat x2 = frameSize.height * apertureRatio;
                    CGFloat x1 = frameSize.width;
                    CGFloat blackBar = (x1 - x2) / 2;
                    if (point.x >= blackBar && point.x <= blackBar + x2) {
                        xc = point.y / y2;
                        yc = 1.f - ((point.x - blackBar) / x2);
                    }
                } else {
                    CGFloat y2 = frameSize.width / apertureRatio;
                    CGFloat y1 = frameSize.height;
                    CGFloat x2 = frameSize.width;
                    CGFloat blackBar = (y1 - y2) / 2;
                    if (point.y >= blackBar && point.y <= blackBar + y2) {
                        xc = ((point.y - blackBar) / y2);
                        yc = 1.f - (point.x / x2);
                    }
                }
            } else if (fillMode == kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill) {
                if (viewRatio > apertureRatio) {
                    CGFloat y2 = apertureSize.width * (frameSize.width / apertureSize.height);
                    xc = (point.y + ((y2 - frameSize.height) / 2.f)) / y2;
                    yc = (frameSize.width - point.x) / frameSize.width;
                } else {
                    CGFloat x2 = apertureSize.height * (frameSize.height / apertureSize.width);
                    yc = 1.f - ((point.x + ((x2 - frameSize.width) / 2)) / x2);
                    xc = point.y / frameSize.height;
                }
            }

            pointOfInterest = CGPointMake(xc, yc);
        }
    }

    return pointOfInterest;
}

+ (void)setFocus:(CGPoint)focus forDevice:(AVCaptureDevice *)device
{
    if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] && [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus])
    {
        NSError *error;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
            [device setFocusPointOfInterest:focus];
            [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }

    if ([device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported] && [device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose])
    {
        NSError *error;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
            [device setExposurePointOfInterest:focus];
            [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Can you tell me why it's not responding when i tap on camera?